# Python Tkinter call a dictionary with a StringVar?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tkinter

I'm working with tkinter in python and I have an annoying bug that I can't seem to fix, although the answer is probably obvious.

I am trying to call a dictionary with a string, but for some reason I get the error:
Type Error: unhashable type: StringVar. Here is a snippet of code with that issue:

```
from Tkinter import *
gpa = Tk()

weightsy = {'0': 2, '.1': 6, '.25':.2, '.5':.56, '.75':75, '1':12}
acadw = StringVar()
acadw.set(".1")
print (weightsy.get(acadw)) #Here is the issue; it should return the integer 6.

mainloop()
```

For extra info, if I remove the tkinter related code (such as the import, gpa = Tk(), StringVar, .set, mainloop()) it works, so I believe it is a tkinter related issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you had to call `set` method of `StringVar` object, you also need to call `get` to retrieve the `str` data.

```
print weightsy[acadw.get()]
```

The dictionary doesn't know to convert your object into a string so it attempts to get the value associated with `acadw`. You get a `TypeError` rather than a `KeyError` since `StringVar` objects happen to be unhashable.

Comment: Thanks, makes much more sense now. Still getting used to tkinter.